# Getting json parse exception

Tags: flutter

I am trying to parse json string to HashMap using json.decode(myString) but I am getting an error.

The following is my json string:

```
{
 'id':'5043' , 
 'artist':'Axwell Λ Ingrosso' ,
 'title':'More Than You Know' ,
 'displayName':'FDM Axwell Ingrosso.mp3' ,
 'duration':'203050',
 'path':'/storage/emulated/0/UCDownloads/FDM_Axwell_Ingrosso.mp3' 
 }
```

I am using jsong.decode(aboveString) to convert but I am getting the following error:

> FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2) {'id':'5043' ,'artist':'Axwell Λ Ingrosso' ,'title':'More Than You Know'

Comment: Some JSON parsers can deal with single quotes, far from all though so I would think using double quotes may solve your problem.

Comment: As already said, JSON does not support single quotes. However, if you can't change the data format, you can use a [yaml](https://pub.dev/packages/yaml) parser instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can tell, you should change all your single quotes to double quotes.

```
{
   'person': 'Λ'
}
```

The above gives me an error, however, this does not:

```
{
   "person": "Λ"
}
```